# The content in my iframe is not clickable in Chrome but works in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, iframe

In my website I have an  iframe that is calling another website(a wordpress one). All I am trying  display is a calendar in my iframe. Since the calendar iframe is larger than the area specified there is a scroll bar down and across. Also in the iframe are buttons that allow the user to select an event on certain days.

All of these buttons/functions work in IE, but NOT in Chrome, nothing is clickable, it is like the iframe is frozen in chrome.

I do not understand why this is occurring!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have something overlaying that iframe? Is the iframe overlaying something? IE is the only browser that transmits click events through transparent iframes afaik. Maybe you can create a self contained example of your problem in jsfiddle.net ? (Code always helps here).

Comment: My website that is under development is  here: http://72.1.219.55/~williams/community.html                          On this page my calendar of events works in IE but not chrome.. maybe this will help? I am not very familiar with jsfiddle.. thanks

Comment: Can't display that webpage. Are you sure it's supposed to be accessible from outside your private network?

Comment: My server was down. it is back up and working now.

Comment: OK. Now I ran your page through the W3 validator, and one of the things it said was " Line 253, Column 152: The sandbox attribute on the iframe element is only supported by Chrome so far. Please be sure to test your page in Chrome." Not sure how that would influence things though.

Comment: Also, the page layout changes very much when the browser width is changed. At some widths, the photos are stretched horizontally. You should look into that. I don't have an answer to your question though. It also goes wrong in Opera and Firefox, so IE is the only one it works in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the div with class `offset-by-four` is on top of the iframe.

It has `padding-left: 300px` (in skeleton.css), but since it also has `position: relative`, I think you meant `left: 300px` instead. Then it will no longer be over the iframe and the iframe can be accessed.

Note, there are other elements with class `offset-by-four` too, so you may have to make other changes as well.

Comment: You're welcome. Hey, could you mark this answer by clicking on the tick mark? Then future visitors will know this question has been resolved.